# Content type different in RabbitListener Spring AMQP using ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Actually I'm using Spring AMQP to consume XML from Rabbit.

Here is my code for Listen the queue.

```
  @RabbitListener(queues = DealerReceiverConfig.P8_QUEUE_NAME, id = Constants.P8_QUEUE_ID)
@SendTo("foo.bar")
public RequestDocument p8ContentReceiveMessage(RequestDocument request) {

System.out.println(request.getCorrelationId());

return request;

}
```

and my  rabbit template configuration is:

```
@Override
@Bean(name = "dealerRabbit")
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplateSeguros(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
template.setMessageConverter(producerMessageConverter());
return template;
}

@Override
@Bean
public MessageConverter producerMessageConverter() {

ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter messageConverter = new ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter();

Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
messageConverter.addDelegate("application/json", jsonMessageConverter);

MarshallingMessageConverter marshaller = new MarshallingMessageConverter();
marshaller.setMarshaller(oxmMarshaller());
marshaller.setUnmarshaller(oxmUnMarshaller());
messageConverter.addDelegate("application/xml", marshaller);

return messageConverter;
}

@Bean
public Marshaller oxmMarshaller() {

Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setPackagesToScan("foo.bar.model");
return marshaller;

}


@Bean
public Unmarshaller oxmUnMarshaller() {

Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setPackagesToScan("foo.bar.model");
return marshaller;

}
```

The problem is when I see the returned message in the @SentTo queue configured, I get the following message.

[Returned message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byuy8.png)

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is not used to send replies from `@RabbitListener`s; you need to add the converter to the `RabbitListenerContainerFactory` (`Simple...` or `Direct...`, depending on which container type you are using).

**EDIT**

It's a bug; you should be able to do this...

```java
    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    @SendTo("bar")
    public Message<String> listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(in.toUpperCase())
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml")
                .build();
    }
```

But the adapter still uses a raw `MessageProperties` which has `application/x-java-serialized-object` as the default CT.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1219

Comment: Thanks Gary for your response, but i am creating a bean with the **ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter** and the Autoconfigure SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory in my **application.yml** is setting it. I´m using Spring AMQP 1.7.4.RELEASE Version

Comment: It's a bug; I opened an issue; you will have to tell the framework which CT to use, but it should work. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your response, I'm using these approach and it works for me.

Comment: It will be correct in the broker but, currently, the header is mapped **after** the converter is called, which means the delegating converter won't know which delegate to use https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/5adbde2e74bd72cf3aefc95e4aa0441ae01663b4/spring-amqp/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/MessagingMessageConverter.java#L102-L113